# Different function parameter types in declaration and definition

Tags: function, go, types

In the standard library, `src/time/sleep.go` has the following:

```
// Interface to timers implemented in package runtime.
// Must be in sync with ../runtime/runtime.h:/^struct.Timer$
type runtimeTimer struct {
    i      int
    when   int64
    period int64
    f      func(interface{}, uintptr) // NOTE: must not be closure
    arg    interface{}
    seq    uintptr
}

func startTimer(*runtimeTimer)
```

The parameter type of `startTimer` is `*runtimeTimer`. `startTimer` implementation is in the `src/runtime/time.go`, as follows:

```
// Package time knows the layout of this structure.
// If this struct changes, adjust ../time/sleep.go:/runtimeTimer.
// For GOOS=nacl, package syscall knows the layout of this structure.
// If this struct changes, adjust ../syscall/net_nacl.go:/runtimeTimer.
type timer struct {
    i int // heap index

    // Timer wakes up at when, and then at when+period, ... (period > 0 only)
    // each time calling f(arg, now) in the timer goroutine, so f must be
    // a well-behaved function and not block.
    when   int64
    period int64
    f      func(interface{}, uintptr)
    arg    interface{}
    seq    uintptr
}

// startTimer adds t to the timer heap.
//go:linkname startTimer time.startTimer
func startTimer(t *timer) {
    if raceenabled {
        racerelease(unsafe.Pointer(t))
    }
    addtimer(t)
}
```

Here the parameter type of `startTimer` is `*timer`.

`*timer` and `*runtimeTimer` are different types. Because according to golang [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity):

> Two pointer types are identical if they have identical base types

And

> A defined type is always different from any other type

`timer` and `runtimeTimer` are both defined types, so `*timer` and `*runtimeTimer` are different types.

According to assignability [rule](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability), assignment of argumetns in the function call shouldn't work either.

Can anybody explain this to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [runtime package function is](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/b5b35be2b8a73b404290f7d0d4c14912a707f9a0/src/runtime/time.go#L106):

```
//go:linkname startTimer time.startTimer
func startTimer(t *timer) {
    if raceenabled {
        racerelease(unsafe.Pointer(t))
    }
    addtimer(t)
}
```

The `//go:linkname` comment is a [compiler directive](https://golang.org/cmd/compile/#hdr-Compiler_Directives):

> //go:linkname localname importpath.name
>
> The //go:linkname directive instructs the compiler to use “importpath.name” as the object file symbol name for the variable or function declared as “localname” in the source code. Because this directive can subvert the type system and package modularity, it is only enabled in files that have imported "unsafe".

This directive tells the compiler to use `time.startTimer` as the object file symbol for this function.

The [time package function](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/b5b35be2b8a73b404290f7d0d4c14912a707f9a0/src/time/sleep.go#L42) is a declaration only. At link time, the time.startTimer name is bound to the function implemented in the runtime package.  This match by name ignores type safety and modularity.

The purpose of these shenanigans is to allow the time package to call a runtime package function without exporting that function from the runtime package.

Comment: "This match by name ignores type safety and modularity", so I can use any type for the parameter type of `time.startTimer` as long as the function name is the same. For instance, I can even use this: `func startTimer()` or `func startTimer(int)`, right?

Comment: The program will build with `func startTimer()` or `func startTimer(int)`, but there's no guarantee that  the program will execute the call without a segfault.